# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook missing from VS2017

Tags: c#

`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` seems to be missing from VS2017. Is it still usable or do I need to use Graph? There seems to be little documentation on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 2017 was probably not installed with 'Office Developer Tools' during the installation.

You need to install and reference it: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/office-tools/

Comment: Thanks all! I found it under COM>